# What plt.subplots() doing here?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below is the code I am trying to execute.

```
x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
H = ax.hist(x, bins=50, alpha=0.5, histtype='stepfilled')
```

Can anybody elaborate what fig, ax = plt.subplots() doing here ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34162641/5120235)

> `plt.subplots()` is a function that returns a tuple containing a figure
> and axes object(s). Thus when using `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` you
> unpack this tuple into the variables `fig` and `ax`. Having `fig` is useful
> if you want to change figure-level attributes or save the figure as an
> image file later (e.g. with `fig.savefig('yourfilename.png')`. You
> certainly don't have to use the returned figure object but many people
> do use it later so it's common to see. Also, all axes objects (the
> objects that have plotting methods), have a parent figure object.

The parameter `bins` is used to set the number of ranges to be used to accumulate the data in those ranges. I don't know where else you have question.

Comment: A perfect answer(+1), you can really do a lot of things with those `fig,ax`, If you wan to get a feel for the same, head to Kaggle and have a look at an EDA kernel..

Comment: @KK2491 I'm happy for that :)